# AIR for Apple Watch?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, adobe, watchkit

I was wondering if adobe air would come out for the apple watch or is there any way to develop with adobe air for iWatch? Thanks!

Comment: it's very unlikely that Adobe would put any money down for AIR to support any new platform or feature. AIR will go on like this until it becomes obsolete. The only cross platform that is sort of required to support everything quick is Unity (that's their business model).

Answer (score 1):

`WatchOS 2` apps require submission to Apple using **LLVM BitCode**. Apple can than compile to native code (currently S1/arm7v) as they update the watch framework and/or hardware and the developer does not have to resubmit their apps to handle those changes.

Adobe has not publicly mentioned adding any additional platforms to Air and it would require a major investment to place a AS3/Air front-end on the LLVM compiler. I, personally, *highly* doubt this feature will ever be seen.

Learning X-code (or license and learn Xamarin/C#) is the only way to go right now (unless someone knows of other third-party development env. that support WatchOS2/WatchKit).

*Add your Vote of support to additional Air platforms:*

- Open Adobe bug/tracker for Windows Phone 8/10 (open since 10/2013): https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=selectBug&CFGRIDKEY=3648920
- Open Adobe bug/tracker for WatchKit & Android Wear:
  https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=4069595